# Testing invalid emails with Rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

This comes from the [Learn Rails by example book](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/modeling-users#sec-presence_validation):

```
 describe "when email format is invalid" do
    it "should be invalid" do
      addresses = %w[user@foo,com user_at_foo.org example.user@foo.
                     foo@bar_baz.com foo@bar+baz.com]
      addresses.each do |invalid_address|
        @user.email = invalid_address
        @user.should_not be_valid
      end      
    end
```

I'm a beginner in **Rspec**. Previously, there was a code like this:

```
  describe "when email is not present" do
    before { @user.email = " " }
    it { should_not be_valid }
  end
```

So I was wondering why the author didn't write the code above like this:

```
 describe "when email format is invalid" do
    before do
      addresses = %w[user@foo,com user_at_foo.org example.user@foo.
                     foo@bar_baz.com foo@bar+baz.com]
      @user.email = invalid_address 
      addresses.each do |invalid_address|
        @user.email = invalid_address
      end 
    end

    it { should_not be_valid }          
 end
```

OK, maybe this code is wrong. But basically, I'm asking why the author didn't use `before` before `it` or put the `address` variable before `it`? (as he did in the previous example)

**EDIT:**

He also does something similar in an further example:

```
 describe "when email address is already taken" do
    before do
      user_with_same_email = @user.dup
      user_with_same_email.email = @user.email.upcase
      user_with_same_email.save
    end

    it { should_not be_valid }
  end
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer lies in what the `before` block is actually doing. In these tests, it is being run fully before the `it` is being run.

So, the first block of code is run (and could be written) as:

```
@user.email = 'user@foo,com'
@user.should_not be_valid
@user.email = 'user_at_foo.org'
@user.should_not be_valid
@user.email = 'example.user@foo.'
@user.should_not be_valid
@user.email = 'foo@bar_baz.com'
@user.should_not be_valid
@user.email = 'foo@bar+baz.com'
@user.should_not be_valid
```

And the second block of code is run (and could be written) as:

```
@user.email = ' '
@user.should_not be_valid
```

But the third block would loop through the entire array *before* getting to the `it`, resulting in only:

```
@user.email = 'foo@bar+baz.com'
@user.should_not be_valid
```

In the final example, he is performing a series of operations against the same object, which are evaluated before the `it`, which only needs to run once to make sense.

Hope this helps, good luck!